# Magento 1.9 Admin Module Error Path menu

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, configuration

Error:

```
 ERR (admin): /index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/mycompany_mymodule/key/
```

when I'm on the admin panel and I click on mycompany -> mymodule menu, appears page with error 404 and inside the logs the line above

Path all File:

```
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\etc\config.xml
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\etc\system.xml
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Helper\Data.php
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Observer.php
app\etc\modules\MyCompany_MyModule.xml
```

Code MyCompany_MyModule.xml:

```
app\etc\modules\MyCompany_MyModule.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends></depends>
    </MyCompany_MyModule>
</modules>
</config>
```

Code config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModule>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyCompany_MyModule>
</modules>    
<!-- -->
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Block</class>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </models>
</global>
<!-- -->
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <file>mycompany/mymodule.xml</file>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <menu>
        <mycompany translate="title" module="mycompany_core">
            <title>mycompany</title>
            <children>
                <mycompany_mymodule translate="title" module="mycompany_mymodule">
                    <title>mycompany new module</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/mycompany_mymodule</action>
                </mycompany_mymodule>
            </children>
        </mycompany>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
<!-- -->
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <mycompany>
                    <title>My Company</title>
                    <children>
                        <mymodule>
                            <title>Settings Example</title>
                        </mymodule>
                    </children>
                </mycompany>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<!-- -->
<default>
    <mycompany_mymodule >
        <mymodule_group>
            <example>10</example>
        </mymodule_group>
    </mycompany_mymodule >
</default>
</config>
```

does anyone see what I was wrong to write?